# Where to have the socket object in your redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, redux, socket.io

I'm working on a chat application using react, redux and socket.io. As we know, redux is very helpful to pass down some state to deep and nested components. I like this idea to store some props as a redux state which will be passed down to some heavily nested component. I'm using [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) library to create the socket object.

I need to pass down the created socket object to some heavily nested components so, I was thinking of creating the socket object on the redux state so that I can consume it easily on the nested components.

Is this a good approach or should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not.

We recently added a [Redux FAQ entry on where websockets should live in a Redux app](https://redux.js.org/faq/codestructure#where-should-websockets-and-other-persistent-connections-live).  Quoting that entry:

> Middleware are the right place for persistent connections like websockets in a Redux app, for several reasons:
>
> - Middleware exist for the lifetime of the application
> - Like with the store itself, you probably only need a single instance of a given connection that the whole app can use
> - Middleware can see all dispatched actions and dispatch actions themselves.  This means a middleware can take dispatched actions and turn those into messages sent over the websocket, and dispatch new actions when a message is received over the websocket.
> - A websocket connection instance isn't serializable, so it doesn't belong in the store state itself

Comment: Examples are always helpful Mark like [this](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/3df1cf5abbac57820a20059287b4be58). Thanks!